# SQL Server Aliased Column Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following statements works on one instance of SQL Server 2005, but fails on another (also SQL Server 2005) with the following error:

> A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.

Does anyone know what would cause this?  Here is a simplified version of the sql statement in question:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (bar INT)


SELECT TOP 150 ID           
FROM                    
(   SELECT  bar as ID,bar FROM  #foo ) tmp
ORDER BY                bar,ID
```

Comment: If I'm reading the simplified version currently, why do you need to sort by both bar and ID? Don't they both hold the same value? To me it reads like you are selecting the same column twice (just aliasing it once) and then trying to sort by the same column twice.

Comment: Tip: Try to use something that has a meaning when you make an example. It's a lot easier to follow an example where the names mean something than trying to keep a lot of nonsense names in the head to try to figure out that the code does.

Comment: @Guffa If I gave the real example, it would be a giant statement with multiple tables that you couldn't reference to reproduce the error.  It would also take way more explanation then anyone would care to hear.  This statement you (or anyone) can run on their local SQL Server to hopefully reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think you might have oversimplified your statement. Do your two databases exhibit the same error/lack of error running the query above?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, they don't exhibit the same error.  One instance of SQL Server 2005 runs the statement fine and returns 0 results (as expected), while another instance of SQL Server 2005 gives the error I posted above.

Comment: Silly question, but have you checked the compatibility level of tempdb (I can't think how this could get screwed up, but since a temp table is involved...)?

Comment: @Don I don't think you need to show us a 5,000 line query to make the example a little more illustrative and meaningful. Maybe it would help explain why you want to order by the same column twice - because maybe there's a different solution than using syntax that is only valid on certain versions (so may break when you add a service pack to the working server).

Comment: @Don: I didn't say that you should post your actual code (although that is preferrable when possible), I just suggested that you should use something that *any* meaning at all, for example `create table #items (num int)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` say? The different behavior may be explained by a fix that was implemented in a service pack, for example. You should try to keep all of your environments consistent in this regard.

Comment: This is a good question. I get the error in my 2005 (9.00.1399.06) but not in the 2008.

Comment: The difference seems to be an error that was fixed in the sql parser somewhere between RTM (9.00.1399.06) and SP3(9.00.4053.00).  

select  SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel')
gives "RTM" on the broken server, and "SP3" on the working servers.

I'm getting an administrator to patch the one server where it isn't working, thanks for the help :)

Comment: So I guess you're going to "fix" it by upgrading the broken server to SP3 and continue using this code that selects the same column twice and orders by both instances? I'd love to be in on the design meetings for that one...

Comment: I think I know what simplification means. I also know what over-simplification means. Can you explain your point in showing me a dictionary entry?

Comment: I was talking to whoever down-voted. I didn't say it was you. Also regarding a "quick fix" - moving from RTM to SP3 is hardly a "quick fix" - there should be plenty of testing involved to make sure that other changes don't break your application.

Comment: +1, although that in our case it was a fix introduced in SP**4** which made the difference. I'll add that there was no actual duplication in the `ORDER BY` in our case.

Comment: @Craig, the duplication doesn't necessarily have to explicitly appear in the `ORDER BY` clause - it can occur if you have potentially ambiguous column names in the `SELECT` list, CTE, derived tables, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think that's more or less what happened -- it was "transitively duplicate." The query itself was generated by the SQL Server ADO.NET provider from a canonical command tree provided by the Entity Framework -- note that both the EF and the ADO.NET provider come from the same MS division as SQL Server! That said, SP4 is quite happy to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good habit to always explicitly reference the table associated with your columns. But in your case, you're still returning one column `bar` twice. Not sure why you'd want to do this but you'd only need to order by one of them.

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (bar INT)


SELECT TOP 150 tmp.ID           
FROM                    
(   SELECT  bar as ID,bar FROM  #foo ) tmp
ORDER BY                tmp.bar
```

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't fix the issue.  I still get the same error I pasted above even if I reference the tmp table.  Again this is a simplification of the issue, so don't read too much into the actual functionality.

Comment: We need more context to understand the underlying issue. Why do you need to return two columns that reference the same column? Why do you need to order by both of them? You've given us nothing but a frivolous and fake example to "read too much into"... there are some pretty smart people floating around here, you don't need to dumb it down that much.

Answer (score 2):

Are the databases running at the same compatibility level?

```
select name, cmptlevel from master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

Comment: I was wondering if it had to do with the compatibility level or some other setting too, but they both are showing a cmptlevel of 80.

Comment: @Don - 80? You're running under SQL Server 2000 rules. You're lucky the machine doesn't spontaneously ignite :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I know, right?  I didn't set up the databases, someone else did and I'm not sure why they used that compatibility level.  However they are both the same, so I don't know what would cause the inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems self-explanatory.

`...Columns in the order by list must be unique.`

bar and ID are the same thing -- i.e., they are not unique.

```
ORDER BY bar,ID
```

should be changed to

```
ORDER BY ID
```

since that's how you're referencing it in your outer query.

PS -- Even if, for whatever reason, one system lets you duplicate an order by operation, and the other doesn't; your best-practice radar ought to be pointing you to not repeating it on either system.  Considering that there's no gain to ordering twice, as the order wouldn't change the second time you repeated the same order operation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the query looks the same? That query should cause the same error in all versions of SQL server.

The compatibility level of a database can cause differences in behaviour, but that should not make a difference in this case.

Comment: I'm running the exact SQL I pasted on both instances.  On one it works and the other it errors.  I just tried another SQL Server 2005 instance on a 3rd server, and also a SQL Server 2008 instance, and both worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error I also encountered. You just need to change the compatibility to at least 90 or higher. This page explains how:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb933794.aspx